# Is it possible to `Import` into Mathematica models from databases like the Biomodels DataBase?

Tags: import

This is probably not a Mathematica question, but maybe I will get lucky.
The https adress "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/BIOMD0000000872" contains many files, the most relevant probably being verma2017.xml, which may be downloaded. Suppose I want to `Import` without downloading. This should be something like

```
model = Import["https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/BIOMD0000000872",
   "SBML"]
```

but this wild guess does not work. I need the result of the import to be
in the format needed to apply `SystemsModelSimulation`

Comment: You have to give the full path to the file: ``Import["https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/model/download/BIOMD0000000872.4?filename=verma2017.xml"]``. I don't think Mathematica natively supports SBML files, however, there seems to be a relevant [MathSBML Package](https://www.celldesigner.org/simulation/Sim_Mathematica.html).